# R gwidgets: Dynamic update of gcheckboxgroup with change in gcombobox input

Tags: r

I am using gcombobox to select the input and populating checkbox dynamically and it's working properly but when I am selecting second input it's not clearing the first output(checkbox) and appending on first one ending up two checkbox and so on..
Is there a way to clear the first input or reflect only one checkbox at one time?

Below is the piece of code-

```
datanames<- c("mydata","yourdata")
f<-function(h,...) 
 {   
x<-(data.frame(get(svalue(h$obj)))) 
    xy<<-names(x)

    ab<-gcheckboxgroup(xy,checked = FALSE,
                    handler = function(h,...) s<<-(svalue(h$obj)),expand=TRUE, container = gf2,use.table=TRUE)
}
w<-gwindow("action")
gp<-ggroup(horizontal=F,container=w)
gf1 = gframe(text="INPUT",cont=w,container=gp)
gf2 = gframe(text="SELECT",cont=w)
cb<-gcombobox(datanames,container=gf1,handler=f,expand=TRUE)
```

I don't know how to clear the gcheckboxgroup with change in gcombobox input.

Thanks!
Om

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is exactly what you have in mind, but you have the `delete` method to remove a child object from a parent container. You just need to hold references to them to use it.

Otherwise you can use the `[<-` method to modify the values in the checkboxgroup that can be selected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I am first time doing it so don't have much idea..can you please take the above piece of code and write the parent child delete method...that will be really helpful for me.Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is likely easiest to just update the available choices on the checkboxgroup when the combobox is changed. A handler for your combobox would look like `function(h,...) cbg[] <- lookup_options[[svalue(cb)]]` where cbg is the checkbox group and cb the combo box. You will have to provide `lookup_options`. I wrote it as a list keyed the values in the combobox.